# Delete the selected text from <ins> tag, based on user inserted data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code below:-

```
<p class="newPara" id="1_0_1">
    <ins data-inserted="1">The ability of </ins><ins data-inserted="2">computers to follow</ins> <ins data-inserted="2">a sequence of operations</ins><ins data-inserted="1">, called a program, </ins><ins data-inserted="2">make computers very flexible and useful.</ins>
</p>
<p class="newPara" id="1_0_2">
    <ins data-inserted="1">Peripheral devices</ins> <ins data-inserted="2">include input devices </ins><ins data-inserted="1">(keyboards, mice, joystick, etc.),</ins> <ins data-inserted="2">output devices (monitor screens, printers, etc.),</ins><ins data-inserted="1"> and input/output devices that perform both functions.</ins>
</p>
```

In case of bulk deletion when text entered by a particular user needs to be deleted ,the remaining text entered by other user need to change to strike through mode and not disappear (ins tag to del tag). This must pertain if multiple fragments are selected as well.

This should be handled on all use cases such as backspace, delete, select delete, select backspace.

My expected result is:-
if user id 1 is selected both paragraph 
[image]
and press delete key, I need the following output

[image]

```
<p class="newPara" id="1_0_1">
    <ins data-inserted="1">The ability of </ins><del data-deleted="1" data-inserted="2">computers to follow</del> <del data-deleted="1" data-inserted="2">a sequence of operations</del><ins data-inserted="1">, called a program, </ins><del data-deleted="1" data-inserted="2">make computers very flexible and useful.</del>
</p>
<p class="newPara" id="1_0_2">
    <ins data-inserted="1">Peripheral devices</ins> <del data-deleted="1" data-inserted="2">include input devices </del><ins data-inserted="1">(keyboards, mice, joystick, etc.),</ins> <del data-deleted="1" data-inserted="2">output devices (monitor screens, printers, etc.),</del><ins data-inserted="1"> and input/output devices that perform both functions.</ins>
</p>
```

I have tried the following code to track the user changes for the single newPara class  its working fine from the following code,

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var $parent = $(sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer);
var $clone = $("<div/>").append(sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
var str = $clone.html();
sel.deleteFromDocument();    
var span = document.createElement("div");
$(span).addClass('tempSelectedDiv');
span.innerHTML = str;
sel.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(span);

$.each($('.tempSelectedDiv').contents(), function(i, val) {
    if(val.nodeName == 'INS' && val.getAttribute('data-ins-author') == abapp.userId){
        val.remove();
    }else{
        $(val).replaceWith('<del data-ins-author="'+insAuth+'" >' + $(val).text() +'</del>');
    }
});
```

but help me to achieve this code for multiple newPara class based on javascript selection

updated the working example in jsfiddle its working for the single newPara class, same principal to be followed across multiple para( multiple newPara)

Link :- https://jsfiddle.net/ww81sbcs/

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing inline instead of creating a new div every time? The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ww81sbcs/15/) and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#deleteKey').click(function(){
  debugger;
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var $cont = $(sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer);

    $cont.find('ins').each(function(idx) {
        if (this.getAttribute('data-inserted') == 1) {
            $(this).replaceWith(function(){
              return $("<del data-inserted='"+1+"' />").append($(this).contents());
            });
        } 
    });

  });
});
```

Explanation:

- `var $cont...`: Like your code, find the common parent element of the selected ranges
- `$cont.find('ins').each(function(idx)`: Search in this container and process every element with `ins` tag
- Logic: If it is "ours" (I assume we are user 1), strike it out. If it not ours do not touch it...

I think the above gives you the result you would expect. If you want to get exactly the output you posted in your question, replace the user id with `2` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Changes i have made here is to

1: Iterate through all the child element of the child element of selected area.

2: Insert the dynamically created div before the button element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#deleteKey').click(function() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var $parent = $(sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer);
    var $clone = $("<div/>").append(sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
    var str = $clone.html();
    sel.deleteFromDocument();
    var span = document.createElement("div");
    $(span).addClass('tempSelectedDiv');
    span.innerHTML = str;

    $(span).insertBefore($(this));

    $('.tempSelectedDiv').children().each(function(i, val) {
      $(val).children().each(function(i, val) {
        if (val.nodeName == 'INS' && val.getAttribute('data-inserted') == 1) {
          $(val).html();
        } else {
          $(val).replaceWith('<del data-inserted="' + 1 + '" >' + $(val).text() + '</del>');
        }
      });
    });

    $('.tempSelectedDiv').contents().unwrap();
    $('.tempSelectedDiv').remove();
  });

  $('.tempSelectedDiv').contents().unwrap();
  $('.tempSelectedDiv').remove();
});
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1qu5c5cf/